# Line Flickers along Tiles in libGDX

Tags: java, camera, libgdx

I am making a simple platformer with a tile-based map. However, when the camera moves there is white flickering which I think occurs along the tile boundaries, but it is hard to tell because they flicker quickly.

What I have tried:

- adding padding to my Tileset. I have 4px padding around each tile, so it's not image bleeding.
- setting the TextureFilter to nearest. It was never on anything else, so Linear wasn't the culprit.
- Casting the camera position to an int. While this doesn't fix the flickering it also makes my camera jerky, so this is the worst possible solution.
- Setting config.useCPUSync to false and config.vSync to true. While I have set vSync to true I can't set CPUSync to false because, as far as I am aware, this is no longer an option. I get a compile time error when I try.

I am just displaying the map by calling TiledMapRendere.render(), so I don't know if the padding from my Tileset or my Nearest TextureFilter are actually being applied correctly, but that is the only possible issue in my rendering process I can think of.

Any other ideas?

Edit:
So I tried rendering manually and I learned a few things.

1. Even if I cast every coordinate for each tile to an int and every coordinate in the camera, there is still flickering, so that is defiantly not the answer. However, I then set the TextureFilter on each tile to Linear and that DID solve the flickering, but I don't like how the textures look so it's not really a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me forever to figure out: everywhere else I looked gave the solutions I tried above.

What I eventually did is extruded the outer pixels by 1 the same way I would have if I expected there to be blur. I think this worked because when the tiles were scaled, the application sometimes had to choose whether to use the outer pixel or a transparent pixel (my margins) and chose a transparent pixel. So now, the margin around each tile is just another pixel of the same color, so if it chooses that pixel it looks the same to us.